# Generate N random numbers within a range with a constant sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, sum, range

I want to generate N random numbers drawn from a specific distribution (e.g uniform random) between [a,b] which sum to a constant C. I have tried a couple of solutions I could think of myself, and some proposed on similar threads but most of them either work for a limited form of problem or I can't prove the outcome still follows the desired distribution.

What I have tried:
Generate N random numbers, divide all of them by the sum of them and multiply by the desired constant. This seems to work but the result does not follow the rule that the numbers should be within [a:b].

Generate N-1 random numbers add 0 and desired constant C and sort them. Then calculate the difference between each two consecutive numbers and the differences are the result. This again sums to C but have the same problem of last method(the range can be bigger than [a:b].

I also tried to generate random numbers and always keep track of min and max in a way that the desired sum and range are kept and come up with this code:

```
bool generate(function<int(int, int)> randomGenerator,
              int min, int max, int len, int sum,
              std::vector<int> &output) {
    /**
     * Not possible to produce such a sequence
     */
    if (min * len > sum)
        return false;
    if (max * len < sum)
        return false;

    int curSum = 0;
    int left = sum - curSum;
    int leftIndexes = len - 1;
    int curMax = left - leftIndexes*min;
    int curMin = left - leftIndexes*max;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int num = randomGenerator((curMin < min) ? min : curMin,
                                  (curMax > max) ? max : curMax);
        output.push_back(num);
        curSum += num;
        left = sum - curSum;
        leftIndexes--;
        curMax = left - leftIndexes * min;
        curMin = left - leftIndexes * max;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This seems to work but the results are sometimes very skewed and I don't think it's following the original distribution (e.g. uniform). E.g:

```
//10 numbers within [1:10] which sum to 50:
generate(uniform, 1, 10, 10, 50, output);
//result:
2,7,2,5,2,10,5,8,4,5 => sum=50
//This looks reasonable for uniform, but let's change to 
//10 numbers within [1:25] which sum to 50:
generate(uniform, 1, 25, 10, 50, output);
//result:
24,12,6,2,1,1,1,1,1,1 => sum= 50
```

Notice how many ones exist in the output. This might sound reasonable because the range is larger. But they really don't look like a uniform distribution.
I am not sure even if it is possible to achieve what I want, maybe the constraints are making the problem not solvable.

Comment: That is called brute force! and you know it might take ages when the input  length is HUGE!

Comment: Note that the function to generate the numbers can fail: it works only if N*a <= C <= N*b. This looks like an interesting problem. The final solution would need to return an error code to indicate whether the problem is solvable.

Comment: @juhist that's why I return bool in the function. And I check possibility in the very begging of the function!

Comment: How big do you expect `N` and `C` to be?

Comment: N can be around 10,000 and C can be about 100GBytes which is a huge integer. This actually for genrating N random files withing [a:b] range with a total C Gigabytes.

Comment: It is logically not possible to solve "I want to generate N random numbers drawn from a specif distribution (e.g uniform random) between [a,b] which sum to a constant C." - so can you explain what higher-level problem you hope to solve by doing this, there may be an alternative which addresses that? (given that you have an answer which you could  here, it may be worth leaving this question as-is, and asking how to approach your outer problem)

Comment: I explained my problem. It's generating N random files within range [a:b] which sum to a total of C bytes. N is around 1000-10000 and range is about [1k:1g] and total is around 50G.

Comment: What I mean is "but *why*?" Do you really need *exactly* 50GB total, *exactly* your target N, and *exactly* a uniform random distribution from a pre-determined range - if so, why? It's impossible. So what problem are you trying to solve with these files?

Comment: I am not trying to solve any problem. I wrote a file system, and I want to generate synthetic workloads. I know for example most of enterprise file servers have a parreto like distribution for file size. So I want to kind of mimic that. No, not exactly 50GB but something like that.

Comment: If you are willing to compromise, then the simplest option is not worry about meeting an impossible target. Let one of your constraints slip. I suggest that your initial re-scaling solution (which lets the size range slip) would work just fine then. If you want some kind of identical workload for comparisons, then seed your random number generator as part of the test setup.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification. Is it asking for X[1]..X[n] such that each X[i] is uniform[a,b] and that sum(X[i]) = c? That's obviously impossible except in very specific situations.

Answer (score 15):

In case you want the sample to follow a uniform distribution, the problem reduces to generate N random numbers with sum = 1. This, in turn, is a special case of the Dirichlet distribution but can also be computed more easily using the Exponential distribution. Here is how:

1. Take a uniform sample v<sub>1</sub> … v<sub>N</sub> with all v<sub>i</sub> between 0 and 1.
2. For all i, 1<=i<=N, define u<sub>i</sub> := -ln v<sub>i</sub> (notice that u<sub>i</sub> > 0).
3. Normalize the u<sub>i</sub> as p<sub>i</sub> := u<sub>i</sub>/s where s is the sum u<sub>1</sub>+...+u<sub>N</sub>.

The p<sub>1</sub>..p<sub>N</sub> are uniformly distributed (in the simplex of dim N-1) and their sum is 1.

You can now multiply these p<sub>i</sub> by the constant C you want and translate them by summing some other constant A like this

q<sub>i</sub> := A + p<sub>i</sub>*C.

**EDIT 3**

In order to address some issues raised in the comments, let me add the following:

- To ensure that the final random sequence falls in the interval [a,b] choose the constants A and C above as A := a and C := b-a, i.e., take q<sub>i</sub> = a + p<sub>i</sub>*(b-a). Since p<sub>i</sub> is in the range (0,1) all q<sub>i</sub> will be in the range [a,b].
- One cannot take the (negative) logarithm -ln(v<sub>i</sub>) if v<sub>i</sub> happens to be 0 because ln() is not defined at 0. The probability of such an event is extremely low. However, in order to ensure that no error is signaled the generation of v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>N</sub> in item 1 above must treat any occurrence of 0 in a special way: consider -ln(0) as +infinity (remember: ln(x) -> -infinity when x->0). Thus the sum s = +infinity, which means that p<sub>i</sub> = 1 and all other p<sub>j</sub> = 0. Without this convention the sequence (0...1...0) would never be generated (many thanks to @Severin Pappadeux for this interesting remark.)
- As explained in the *4th comment attached to the question* by @Neil Slater it is logically impossible to fulfill all the requirements of the original framing. Therefore any solution must relax the constraints to a proper subset of the original ones. Other comments by @Behrooz seem to confirm that this would suffice in this case.

**EDIT 2**

One more issue has been raised in the comments:

*Why rescaling a uniform sample does not suffice?*

In other words, *why should I bother to take negative logarithms?*

The reason is that if we just rescale then the resulting sample won't distribute uniformly across the segment (0,1) (or [a,b] for the final sample.)

To visualize this let's think 2D, i.e., let's consider the case N=2. A uniform sample (v<sub>1</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>) corresponds to a random point in the square with origin (0,0) and corner (1,1). Now, when we normalize such a point dividing it by the sum s=v<sub>1</sub>+v<sub>2</sub> what we are doing is projecting the point onto the diagonal as shown in the picture (keep in mind that the diagonal is the line x + y = 1):

[image]

But given that green lines, which are closer to the principal diagonal from (0,0) to (1,1), are longer than orange ones, which are closer to the axes x and y, the projections tend to accumulate more around the center of the projection line (in blue), where the scaled sample lives. This shows that a simple scaling won't produce a uniform sample on the depicted diagonal. On the other hand, it can be proven mathematically that the negative logarithms do produce the desired uniformity. So, instead of copypasting a mathematical proof I would invite everyone to implement both algorithms and check that the resulting plots behave as this answer describes.

(**Note:** [here](http://www.caesarsystems.com/blog/capabilities/probabilistic-splits/#.VQ7HCVwayJU) is a blog post on this interesting subject with an application to the Oil & Gas industry)

Comment: Isn't this same as what I mentioned as my first solution and what @kuroi neko explained and extended?

Comment: I don't think so. The key point in my answer consists in applying the natural logarithm to the uniform sample: ui := -ln(vi), which I don't see in the other answer.

Comment: Ok,I am gonna try in R to see how it turns out.

Comment: This does not follow the constraint that numbers should be within range [a:b]

Comment: ? Sure it does
n_i = a + p_i*(b-a), for p_i between 0 and 1. Also worth mentioning that if original v_i=0 means p_i=1, and every other p_k = 0

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux so when do you multiply pi by C?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux notice that since the vi are random in (0,1) no vi is ever 0. But even if you take a closed interval [0,1] the probability of sampling 0 is negligible so you can ignore that case.

Comment: @Behrooz the idea is to take C=b-a. Note also that you cannot have everything, however, what you can have is a uniformly distributed sample in [a,b] given by a + pi*(b-a). Se also the Neil Slater comment attached to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if I can relax range or sum then yes, many of the methods work fine. Thanks for you solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia no, you cannot ignore it, v_i could get 0 if you use standard c++11/14 generators/distribution, look at the document

Comment: @Behrooz just for fun I've implemented this sampling, seems to work in 2D and 3D. Code is at `https://github.com/Iwan-Zotow/SimplexSampling`,  enjoy!

Comment: The question states that these random numbers must be within a specific interval that has no correlation with the final sum. If the problem is just to find a random spread, no need to summon Mr. Dirichlet, I think. Just scale each number to the desired sum and Bob should be your uncle.

Comment: @kuroineko Could you please elaborate a little bit more? I'm not following you.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia your method does not guarantee that each random number will be in the specified [a,b] range. Scaling the numbers to match a given sum is only half of the problem.

Comment: @kuroineko Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated my answer with some clarifications. Please let me know if you still have any issue with my answer. And again, thanks a lot for reviewing.

Comment: Well the edit sums it up: you cannot meet all the requirements simultaneously. Given that, I don't think resorting to a complicated logarithmic approach is necessary. Simply drawing **N** random numbers and rescaling them to reach the needed sum should do the trick with much less effort. You can ensure each number is greater than **a** (provided **C** is greater than **Na**), but the upper bound **b** is governed by the **C/N-a** value.

Comment: @kuroineko I see. Please read my second EDIT and let me know if it addresses your concern.

Comment: Good point. I see it now. Since the sum is itself a random variable, using it to tweak the samples changes the repartition. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia So 'ln' does the trick for uniform distribution. Do you have any idea how would this behave in case of other distributions?

Comment: @Behrooz for another distribution you need to sample using a general Dirichlet distribution (which doesn't have a simple implementation.) The uniform case is simple because of the -ln() trick. But this is the simplest case of all possibilities regarding Dirichlet distributions with different parameters.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia I don't believe `must discard any occurrence of 0 replacing it with a new sample.` When one of the `v` is sampled to 0, it means there would be plus infinity in nominator and in denominator, which leads to logical conclusion - this is special case where for this `v` outgoing `p` shall be set to 1 and all other `p_i` shall be equal to 0. Otherwise, there is no way you could generated `\vec{p}` of `(0,0,0,...,1,...0,0,0,0)` kind

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Many thanks for this interesting remark! I've updated the answer (see se second item of EDIT 3.)

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to simplify the problem. 
By substracting the lower bound, we can reduce it to finding **N** numbers in **[0,b-a]** such that their sum is **C-Na**.

Renaming the parameters, we can look for **N** numbers in **[0,m]** whose sum is **S**.

Now the problem is akin to partitioning a segment of length **S** in **N** distinct sub-segments of length **[0,m]**.

I think the problem is simply not solvable.

if S=1, N=1000 and m anything above 0, the only possible repartition is one 1 and 999 zeroes, which is nothing like a random spread.

There is a correlation between **N**, **m** and **S**, and even picking random values will not make it disappear.

For the most uniform repartition, the length of the sub-segments will follow a gaussian curve with a mean value of **S/N**.

If you tweak your random numbers differently, you will end up with whatever bias, but in the end you will never have both a uniform [a,b] repartition and a total length of C, unless the length of your [a,b] interval happens to be 2C/N-a.

Answer (score 1):

For my answer I'll assume that we have a uniform distribution.

Since we have a uniform distribution, every tuple of `C` has the same probability to occur. For example for `a = 2, b = 2, C = 12, N = 5` we have `15` possible tuples. From them `10` start with `2`, `4` start with `3` and `1` starts with `4`. This gives the idea of selecting a random number from `1` to `15` in order to choose the first element. From `1` to `10` we select `2`, from `11` to `14` we select `3` and for `15` we select `4`. Then we continue recursively.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine generator(time(0));
int a = 2, b = 4, n = 5, c = 12, numbers[5];

// Calculate how many combinations of n numbers have sum c
int calc_combinations(int n, int c) {
    if (n == 1) return (c >= a) && (c <= b);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) sum += calc_combinations(n - 1, c - i);
    return sum;
}

// Chooses a random array of n elements having sum c
void choose(int n, int c, int *numbers) {
    if (n == 1) { numbers[0] = c; return; }

    int combinations = calc_combinations(n, c);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, combinations - 1);
    int s = distribution(generator);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        if ((sum += calc_combinations(n - 1, c - i)) > s) {
            numbers[0] = i;
            choose(n - 1, c - i, numbers + 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() { choose(n, c, numbers); }
```

Possible outcome:

```
2
2
3
2
3
```

This algorithm won't scale well for large `N` because of overflows in the calculation of combinations (unless we use a big integer library), the time needed for this calculation and the need for arbitrarily large random numbers.

Comment: This looks interesting, but with the scale of my numbers (N is around 1000-10000 and range is about [10^3:10^9] and sum is around 50^9) this will never terminate.

Comment: @Behrooz: and calc_combinations will rapidly overflow any standard integer type.

Answer (score 0):

well, for n=10000 cant we have a small number in there that is not random?

maybe generating sequence till `sum > C-max` reached and then just put one simple number to sum it up.

1 in 10000 is more like a very small noise in the system.

Comment: I am not sure how that would affect the final distribution, and "a very small noise" might need to be quantified.

Comment: the main point is that numbers are generated randomly. so it is possible that the next number is going to be the same number u selected manually.
your brute force algorithm is somehow doing the same. u repeat it until one of those random situations come out. so just create the random situation u want.

Comment: for quantifying the noise, get next random from your sequence generator, calculate distance of your last number from it. divide it to 10^4. repeat it several times and calculate mean :P ( how is that for quantifying!!)

Answer (score 0):

Although this was old topic but I think I got a idea. Consider we want N random number which sum is C and each random between a and b. To solve problem, we create N holes and prepare C balls, for each time we ask each hole "Do you want another ball?". If no, we pass to next hole, else, we put a ball into the hole. Each hole has a cap value: b-a. If some hole reach the cap value then always pass to next hole.

Example:
3 random numbers between 0 and 2 which sum is 5.

simulation result:
1st run: -+-
2nd run: ++-
3rd run: ---
4th run: +*+
final:221

-:refuse ball
+:accept ball
*:full pass

Comment: That's a good solution. The only issue is that the numbers generated will have very small variation.