# Generate N uniform random numbers with sum of one

Tags: r, random

I am trying to generate 100 uniform random numbers in range [0.005, 0.008] with sum of one. I was looking to several questions which were relevant to my concerns but I did not find my answer.
Could anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Given that you have 100 numbers and each number's maximum value is 0.008, the maximum sum is 0.8, which is less than the desired sum of 1.

Comment: The important thing to notice here is that the summation constraint means the variables are not independent.  Can you be more specific as to what you need these numbers for?

Answer (score 3):

To start, I'm going to slightly modify your example, assuming the 100 variables are bounded by [0.008, 0.012] and that they sum to 1 (this ensures there are feasible points in the set you're sampling).

The ["hit and run" algorithm](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.32.6.1296) uniformly samples over a bounded subset of an n-dimensional space. For your case, we have n=100 dimensions; let's define corresponding variables `x_1, x_2, ..., x_100`. Then we have three types of constraints to bound our region of the space we want to sample from.

**Variables are lower bounded by 0.008** -- this can be captured by the following linear inequalities:

```
x_1 >= 0.008
x_2 >= 0.008
...
x_100 >= 0.008
```

**Variables are upper bounded by 0.012** -- this can be captured by the following linear inequalities:

```
x_1 <= 0.012
x_2 <= 0.012
...
x_100 <= 0.012
```

**Variables sum to 1** -- this can be captured by:

```
x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_100 = 1
```

Let's say we wanted to get 10 sets of variables that are uniformly distributed within our space. Then we can use the `hitandrun` package in R in the following way:

```
library(hitandrun)
n <- 100
lower <- 0.008
upper <- 0.012
s <- 1
constr <- list(constr = rbind(-diag(n), diag(n), rep(1, n), rep(-1, n)),
               dir = rep("<=", 2*n+2),
               rhs = c(rep(-lower, n), rep(upper, n), s, -s))
samples <- hitandrun(constr, n.samples=10)
dim(samples)
# [1]  10 100
```

Note that this takes quite a long while to run (slightly less than 2 hours in my case) because we are sampling in a high-dimensional space (dimension n=100), and to ensure uniform samples the hit and run algorithm actually performs O(n^3) iterations for each sample it draws. You may be able to decrease the runtime my adjusting the `thin` parameter to the function, though this could affect the independence of your draws.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to generate the random numbers step by step. In each step take care that the remaining sum is not getting to large, nor to small. In the final step these random numbers are permuted randomly:

```
N <- 100

lowerBound <- 0.008
upperBound <- 0.012
Sum        <- 1

X <- rep(NA,N)
remainingSum <- Sum

for (i in 1:(N-1))
{
  a <- max( lowerBound, remainingSum-(N-i)*upperBound )
  b <- min( upperBound, remainingSum-(N-i)*lowerBound )

  A <- ceiling(1e+8*a)
  B <- floor(1e+8*b)

  X[i] <- ifelse( A==B, A, sample(A:B,1)) / 1e+8

  remainingSum <- remainingSum - X[i]
}

X[N] <- remainingSum

X <- sample(X,N)
```

I'm sorry for the `for`-loop, but it is a base R solution and it seems to work.

```
> sum(X)
[1] 1
> min(X)
[1] 0.00801727
> max(X)
[1] 0.01199241
> plot(X)
```

[image]

The distribution is not exactly, but almost uniform. I repeated the calculation 5000 times and stored the n-th sample in `X[,n]`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

All positions together:

[image]

Near the lower bound and the upper bound the frequency is increased, but in the rest of the interval between the bounds it is nearly constant.

Here is an idea how to make the distribution even more uniform:
Combine some numbers near the lower and upper boundary and "throw them into the middle":

- Pick `x1` near the lower boundary and `x2` near the upper boundary. Their mean will be approximately the center of the interval.
- Draw a random number `y` such that `y` and `x1+x2-y` are contained in the interval.
- Replace `x1` and `x2` by `y` and `x1+x2-y`.
- Repeat until the peaks at the boundaries vanish.

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable heuristic (much quicker than my solution!), but it's worth noting that it doesn't sample uniformly from the set of feasible n-dimensional vectors in general. To see why, consider sampling 100 elements with target sum 1.196. By symmetry every element should have mean 0.01196 (extremely close to the max), and elements below 0.01 would be vanishingly rare. However your first element has expected value 0.01 and takes a value below 0.01 with probability 50%.

Comment: The mean is a property of the whole sample, not a single element. Perhaps you want to repeat the experiment 1000000 times and then calculate the mean of the elements at position 1. Because the numbers are FINALLY PERMUTED this mean is equal to the mean of the whole sample. The final permutation makes the positions indistinguishable. The "random process" at position 1 is the same as that at position 2 and so on. If you don't believe it, check it.

Comment: OK, consider a simple case with n=3, bounds [0, 1], and sum 2. Via integration, if we sample evenly from the set of possible (x, y, z) tuples that satisfy the bounds and sum condition then the probability that any of the three values is below 0.1 is 3%. In 100k samples, my method returned 3029 samples (3.029%) with one of the three values below 0.1. In 100k samples, your method returned 10947 samples (10.947%) with one of the three values below 0.1.

Comment: One other quick comment -- it would be more efficient to use `runif` to sample uniformly between `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the discussion of sampling uniformity and how one might work to address it (+1)! I think this is a nice approach because it has better asymptotic runtime than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about what these numbers will be used for, the problem is ambiguous.  By probing some lower-dimensional examples, we can see that what "uniform" means here is unfortunately vague.  If the plan is to use this for some sort of Monte Carlo based simulation, the results you get will most likely not be useful.

Let's look at the problem with `n=4`, constraint `[210,300]` and total as `1000`.

We generate (inefficiently) an exhaustive list of all discrete values that match the criteria

```
values <- 210:300
df <- subset(expand.grid(a=values, b=values, c=values, d=values), a+b+c+d==1000)
```

The distribution of a, b, c, and d will be identical because of symmetry.  The distribution looks like

```
> plot(prop.table(table(df$a)), type='l')
```

[image: distribution of single variable]

This problem will only get worse with higher dimensions.  The "summing to 1" requirement has the effect of restricting the sampling to an N-1-dimensional hyperplane, and the individual component constraints serve to carve the feasible subset into a polyhedron (based on the intersection of the N-dimensional hypercube with the plane embedded in N-space).

In 3 dimensions, the subspace looks like the intersection of a plane and a cube; so a hexagon in the middle, and triangles on the ends.  Easily verified by looking at the plot of the first two principle components

```
> values <- 100:150; df <- subset(expand.grid(a=values, b=values, c=values), a + b + c==370); df2 <- as.data.frame(predict(princomp(df)))
> plot(df2$Comp.1, df2$Comp.2)
```

[image: principle component analysis of results]

In summary, this problem is much more difficult to reasonably solve than it looks without some knowledge of what the usage intent looks like.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you say `we can see that what "uniform" means here is unfortunately vague`. Usually when folks talk about sampling uniformly from a space they mean each region with equal measure has the same probability of being drawn. Of course this could imply that some values for individual elements could be much more common than others. For instance, when sampling 3 values bounded by [0, 1] that sum to 2, naturally we should expect more values close to 1 than values close to 0.

Comment: @josilber: yes, but uniform over the volume or on the margins?  No-one has brought up an appropriately shifted/scaled Dirichlet deviate as a possibility yet ...

Comment: @BenBolker I assumed uniform over volume but I see your point. I was recently pointed to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187044/generate-n-random-numbers-within-a-range-with-a-constant-sum which describes the transformed Dirichlet deviate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified Metropolis-Hastings based solution. Note that I'm not hitting convergence yet with your constraint; but, it's quite close:

```
simple_MH <- function(n= 100, low= 0.005, up= 0.02, max_iter= 1000000) {
  x <- runif(n, low, up)
  sum_x <- sum(x)
  iter <- 0

  if (sum_x == 1) return(x)
  else {
    while (sum_x != 1 & iter < max_iter) {
      iter <- iter + 1
      if (sum_x > 1) {
        xt <- sample(which(x > mean(x)), 1)  
      } else {
        xt <- sample(which(x < mean(x)), 1)
      }

      propose <- runif(1, low, up)
      d_prop <- dnorm(propose, 1 / n, sqrt(1/12 *(up - low)^2))
      d_xt   <- dnorm(x[xt], 1 / n, sqrt(1/12 *(up - low)^2))
      alpha <- d_prop / d_xt

      if (alpha >= 1) {
        x[xt] <- propose
        sum_x <- sum(x)
      } else {
        acc <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1, prob= c(alpha, 1-alpha))
        if (acc) {
          x[xt] <- propose
          sum_x <- sum(x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(list(x=x, iter= iter))
}

# try it out:
test <- simple_MH() # using defaults (note not [0.005, 0.008])
test2 <- simple_MH(max_iter= 5e6)
R> sum(test[[1]]) # = 1.003529
R> test[[2]] # hit max of 1M iterations
R> sum(test2[[1]]) # = 0.9988
R> test2[[2]] # hit max of 5M iterations
```