# How do a make sure an arbitrary number of weights sum to 1 (Python)?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I have a simulated annealing algorithm and I have a function like

`result = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... + wn*xn`

every loop of the simulated annealing when new `w` values are chosen how do you make sure that the sum of `w` always equal to 1 and that no individual `w` value is less that 0?

Thank you very much folks!

Comment: Have you tried directly translating that pseudocode into Python with `if sum(w) == 1 and all(item >= 0 for item in w)`?

Comment: You might not want to compare exactly to one, [lest you start thinking floating-point math is broken.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are the w_i generated randomly? If true be aware that normalizing by their sum won't produce a uniform distribution. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187687/4081336) to see how to solve this.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right @Leandro Caniglia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use NumPy.
2. That way, instead of `result = w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... + wn*xn` you can do `result = np.dot(w, x)`.
3. The condition you want on `w` seems like it could come from:

   ```
   non_negative_w = np.abs(w)
   sum_w = np.sum(non_negative_w)
   normalized_non_negative_w = non_negative_w / sum_w
   ```