# How to Generate random number in a specific range and sum?

Tags: c++

It is not my homework; it is just what I come up when I read about C++. I'm still a beginner. My question here is Can I generate the random numbers that has a particular range and sum. For example, I want to generate 15 numbers and the range from 2 to 5, and the sum is 60. From the book I read, I can generate the random numbers using #include . 
uniform_int_distribution randomInt{2, 5}; //it helps me to generate random number from 2 to 5.
default_random_engine{static_cast(time(0))}; //it helps me to generate different sequences of number if I run the program second time. It actually uses the #include  for time(0).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int randomNumber = 0;

    default_random_engine engine{ static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)) };
    uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> randomInt{ 1, 6 };


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
    {

        randomNumber = randomInt(engine);

        cout << randomNumber << endl; 

    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This is just basically how it generate different number

Comment: No, that's not how random numbers work. This has nothing to do with C++ or programming in general.

Comment: Do you have tried to do some code, it would be great to share a piece of code where you have tried to do this.

Comment: they have randomInt(engine) to generate the different number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate N random numbers within a range with a constant sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187044/generate-n-random-numbers-within-a-range-with-a-constant-sum)

Comment: _It is not my homework_ ... well if you have to state that it probably *is* ;-)

Comment: Would a professor give you that problem if you first begin to study C++? I know it's not for the beginner level, that's why I post the question to ask if there is a possible way to generate these number. At least, my professor didn't.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is only one solution to the problem:

2a + 3b + 4c + 5d = 60

a + b + c + d = 15

a, b, c, d > 0

It would be solved using linear programming.

Once you have solved that, you can take the solution and do a random shuffle to get a random permutation of that.

The benefit is that you will get a uniformly random permutation.

If you don't care about efficiency and the uniformity of distribution of solution then you can generate 15 numbers between 2 and 5 and see if they sum to 60 if not generate another 15 numbers, etc

Comment: To improve the efficiency use a horde of threads to each generate and stop when the first one hits 60. I am not sure if this would be needed due to the probability of getting 60 with 15 values given the range 2-5. If the probability is low, threads might help if they are independent. Otherwise one thread should be good enough and just retry