# Divide / Hand out random amount

Tags: javascript, math, random

Lets say I have **8 people** and **5000 apples**.
I want to hand out all the apples to all 8 people so i have **no apples left.**
But everyone should get a **different amount**

What would be the best way to give them all out?

I started of with this:

```js
let people = 8
let apples = 5000

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

while (people--) {
  // last person get the rest
  let x = people ? getRandomInt(0, apples) : apples

  // subtract how many apples i got left
  apples -= x 

  console.log(`Giving person ${people + 1} ${x} apples (got ${apples} left)`)
}
```

But the thing I don't like about this is that the last person get very few apples (sometimes less then 5 apples) and the first person gets way more then the others

Comment: You could take 80% of the apples and divide those evenly among them, then randomize the last 20%.  Adjust percentages to taste.

Comment: you could also set a minimum percentage of apples based on the number of people  var minPercentage = (100 / people) - 10// or whatever you want the variance to be then check to see if the apples per person equal or are greater than the min percentage. You would need an array to store them in, and to run the checks before you printed anything out.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: Does it have to be random?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be random

Comment: There are alot of different ways; one of the imore infamous ones is to try to pick N random numbers, _uniformly distributed_, that sum to M (it's not as obvious as it sounds).  Without any other information, I'd suggest that what you probably want is to emulate a process whereby you choose a random person to give an apple to, 5000 times, which usually gives everyone broadly the same number of apples, but could, with extremely low probability, give all the apples to one person.

Comment: For a simple solution to the problem of "picking N random numbers uniformly distributed that sum to M" mentioned by @sh1 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29187687/4081336)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figure it out. Was just a little tweeking.

`let x = people ? getRandomInt(0, Math.floor(apples / people)) : apples`

```js
let people = 8
let apples = 5000

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}

while (people--) {
  // last person get the rest
  let x = people ? getRandomInt(0, Math.floor(apples / people)) : apples

  // subtract how many apples i got left
  apples -= x 

  console.log(`Giving person ${people + 1} ${x} apples (got ${apples} left)`)
}
```

Still which nobody got less then 100 apples or more then 1000 but this will do. Otherwise it get just more complex. the next day i may only have 2500 apples and 6 people...

Answer (score 1):

If you need random yet 'balanced' results each time, you need to prioritize either balance - or randomness. Here's one possible solution following your 'widestGap' requirement:

```js
function randomDeltas(length, widestGap, remToGet) {
  // widestGap >= length * 2 - 1
  let deltas = [];
  let sum = 0;
  let start = 0;
  let origLength = length;
  while (length--) {
    start += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * widestGap);
    deltas.push(start);
    sum += start;
  }
  
  let rem = sum % origLength;
  let correction = remToGet - rem;
  if (correction !== 0) {
    sum -= deltas[0];
    deltas[0] += correction;
    if (deltas[0] >= deltas[1]) {
      deltas[0] -= origLength;
    }
    else if (deltas[0] < deltas[1] - widestGap) {
      deltas[0] += origLength;
    }
    sum += deltas[0];
  }
  return {
    deltas,
    sum
  };  
}

function randomDistinctDistribute(apples, people) {
  let rem = apples % people;
  let { deltas, sum } = randomDeltas(people, people * 2 - 1, rem);
  let div = (apples - sum) / people;
  let distribution = [];
  while (deltas.length) {
    distribution.push(div + deltas.shift());
  }
  return distribution;
}

console.log(randomDistinctDistribute(5000, 8));
console.log(randomDistinctDistribute(2500, 6));
```

Here the idea is to randomize the deltas (to make sure that gap never becomes big), then apply those deltas to divisor.

---

Here's the original (deterministic) approach to get balanced distribution with distinct values:

```
function distinctDividents(apples, people) {
  let distribution = [];
  let div = Math.floor(apples / people);
  let rem = apples % people;
  if (people % 2) {
    distribution.push(div);
    people--;
  }
  let half = people / 2;
  let i = 1;
  while (i <= half) {
    distribution.push(div - i);
    distribution.unshift(div + i);
    i++;
  }
  if (rem) {
    distribution[0] += rem; 
  }
  return distribution;
}

console.log(distinctDividents(5000, 8));
```

Comment: clever, but one problem is that it is predictable. Always the same result every time i run it. I want it to be random each time. I also thought it was to equally divided (the differensen was just 15 between max and min)

Comment: Updated the code with illustration for random balanced distribution approach. Not that you can change the params as you wish (try 2500 and 6 for example; or even 2600 and 9!).