# sampling uniformly (x,y,z) such that x+y+z=0

Tags: random, geometry

I am trying to sample uniformly from the set of all point (x,y,z) such that x+y+z = 0 and -1<=x<=1, -1<=y<=1 and -1<=z<=1.

My idea was the following: I sampled uniformly from the 6 dimensional simplex(following [this suggestion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex)), i.e. from the set of points (a,b,c,d,e,f) such that a+b+c+d+e+f= 0 and 0<=a<=1, 0<=b<=1, 0<=c<=1, 0<=d<=1, 0<=e<=1 and 0<=f<=1.
Since geometrically the set of all points satifying (1) is a hexagon with vertices (-1,1,0),  (-1,0,1),  (0,-1,1),  (1,-1,0),  (1,0,-1) and  (0,1,-1), I computed 
(x,y,z) = a*(-1,1,0)+b*(-1,0,1)+c*(0,-1,1)+d*(1,-1,0)+e*(1,0,-1)+f*(0,1,-1).
I sampled half a million points following this method, but unfortunatly, it seems like the points are not uniformly distributed.

[image: Here is a plot]

Does anybody know what the problem is with this and how to correct it?

Comment: Quoting the source answer: "*... if you sample uniformly from the hypercube, this wont give you a uniform sampling in the simplex. However, if you sample from the hypercube with an appropriate Exponential Distribution, than this effect cancels out.*"

Comment: No, I am doing the algorithm where one sorts n-1 points and then takes differences. Thats the algorithm which is proposed directly above the one you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, and that one does not give the desired result, but the Normalized Exponential one does.

Comment: quoting from his answer(emphasis mine): "For your problem it would mean that you take n−1 random numbers from the interval (0,1), then you add a 0 and 1 to get a list of n+1 numbers. You sort the list and then you record the differences between two consecutive elements. This gives you a list of n number that will sum up to 1. **Moreover this sampling is uniform.** This idea can be found in Donald B. Rubin, The Bayesian bootstrap Ann. Statist. 9, 1981, 130-134."

Comment: The resulting sampled point distribution is uniform, but not the random number distribution. OP first uses the naive uniform distribution for (0, 1) and shows that it does not give correct results, and then the exponential one which *does*.

Comment: I think you are misreading the answer. The author is giving two solutions. The first one is the one I quoted above. In the second one he explains that one cannot normalize n uniformly distributed random variables, i.e. project the unit cube onto the simplex. One can rectify this by choosing points according to an exponential distribution. But this has nothing todo with the first solution, which is valid.

Comment: You might want to check this answer too  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29187687/4081336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hexagon consists of three parallelograms. So it is worth to choose randomly one of these parallelograms then uniformly generate point inside chosen one.

Base vectors for parallelograms:

```
v[0][0] = (-1,1,0)
v[0][1] = (0,-1,1)
v[1][0] = (0,-1,1)
v[1][1] = (1,0,-1)
v[2][0] = (1,0,-1)
v[2][1] = (-1,1,0)
```

Generation steps:

```
np = randominteger(0..2)
t = randomfloat(0..1)
u = randomfloat(0..1)
point = t * v[np][0] + u * v[np][1]
```